# Почему вместо копирования через bat файл у меня открывается копируемый файл?

Tags: windows, bat, copy, автозагрузка

Расположил батник в "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"

и файл, который он должен скопировать при авторизации в windows.
Вместо копирования файл просто открывается.
Содержимое батника:

```
copy KM_TWAIN1.ini %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Kyocera\KM_TWAIN
```

Comment: `cmd /c copy ...`

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!